# How to disable the Chrome notification bell menu bar icon in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications

Last Chrome version in Mac OS X adds a bell icon on menu bar which I want to disable/make dissappear.

The question is... How?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125775/how-do-i-remove-the-google-chrome-notifications-bell-icon-from-the-mac-os-x-menu

Answer (score 5):

Go to Chrome, click on "Chrome" on your menu bar and select "Hide notifications icon".